# how to fix( Strapi-Plugin-users-permission > grant-koa@5.4.8nhas unmet peer dependency "koa@>=2.0.0"

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, strapi

**how to fix( Strapi-Plugin-users-permission > grant-koa@5.4.8nhas unmet peer dependency  "koa@>=2.0.0"**

im working on react and headless CMS starpi API.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to solve it dssssssssssssssssssss: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9120